# How can I listen to specific keyboard presets online?

Tags: sound, korg

I would like to listen to a keyboard preset online. I know the model of the keyboard and the preset number, how could I find a recording?

As an example, I'm interested in the Korg Kronos 88. If I wanted to listen to preset I-A000, how could I do so?

Comment: Questions that are requests for external resources are [off-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Hey, I've edited your question because resource requests are off-topic. Hopefully the edited version will pass muster. Feel free to revert if you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any comprehensive way of doing this; either for the Kronos specifically, or any keyboard. The best-placed person to do this would be the manufacturer, and I haven't found one with a comprehensive audition facility.

With that in mind, here's a few ideas:

The most exhaustive option is to find a nice person who might help you. Stack Exchange is not the venue, but there are keyboard forums which might be of help. For your example, there are forums dedicated to the Kronos. Perhaps if you ask nicely someone might oblige? This is more likely to work if you just want to hear one or two specific sounds. Fronting up with a list of 50 might stretch the friendship a little bit.

I've also had success in searching YouTube for comparison videos. However, these are not at all comprehensive, and you have to watch the whole video to see if it's got the patch you're interested in. Soundcloud has also been of use. Search terms like "[keyboard name] demo" are of use. In my experience, they sometimes list the patch names in the video, or in the description text.

For the record, I went through this exact procedure with the Kronos before I bought one about three years ago. I didn't find everything I wanted, but I did find enough to confirm what I needed to know.

The obvious non-answer is to find a music store with the keyboard in question, and play it yourself. But that's not practical for a lot of people; myself included. Or make a friend who owns that instrument. In fact, a friend did exactly that with mine last week.

Answer (score 1):

There is someone in Finland working on a project to do just this:
https://playasynth.com

They don't have that specific synthesizer available, yet, but you could sign up for the mailing list and see if they do, eventually.

Right now, only the Minilogue and OB-6 are available, I think. But I haven't signed up yet.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Seems like his back-end API service is down though.  Will try again another time.

Answer (score -1):

I found what appears to be a very old sample list - JPEG's are still on 3.5" floppy:  http://www.synthmania.com/Korg%20DSS-1%20Sound%20Library/ :

```
DWGS synthesizer presets/
KSDU-001 Piano/
KSDU-002 Brass/
KSDU-003 Strings & Choir/
KSDU-004 Guitar & Bass/
KSDU-005 Japanese Inst/
KSDU-006 Indian Inst/
KSDU-007 Bass Groups/
KSDU-008 Pianos II/
KSDU-009 Electric Guitars 1 & 2/
KSDU-010 Acoustic Guitar/
KSDU-011 Group & Orchestra Hits/
KSDU-012 Brass Hits/
KSDU-013 Combined Groups/
KSDU-014 Sound Effects/
KSDU-015 Drums/
KSDU-016 Latin Percussion/
KSDU-017 Percussion/
KSDU-018 Strings/
KSDU-019 Voices/
KSDU-020 Brass/
KSDU-021 Guitars/
KSDU-022 Pianos/
KSDU-023 Flutes & Harp/
KSDU-024 Woodwinds/
KSDU-025 Strings/
KSDU-026 Harpsichord & Organ/
KSDU-027 Brass/
KSDU-028 Brass & Sax/
KSDU-029 Percussion/
KSDU-030 Electric Guitars/
KSDU-031 Percussion II/
KSDU-032 Orchestral Perc/
KSDU-033 Combination Snds/
KSDU-034 Woodwinds/
KSDU-035 Vibes, Glock, Piano, Clav/
KSDU-036 Strings II/
KSDU-037 Mixed Percussion/
KSDU-038 Voices/
KSDU-039 Woodwind & Strng/
KSDU-040 Strings/
KSDU-041 Wind Instruments/
KSDU-042 Brass/
KSDU-043 Reeds 1/
KSDU-044 Reeds 2/
KSDU-045 Guitars (Acoust)/
KSDU-046 Guitars (Rock)/
KSDU-047 Bass/
KSDU-048 Electric Piano 1/
KSDU-049 Electric Piano 2/
KSDU-050 MIDI Combos/
KSDU-051 Japanese Inst 2/
KSDU-052 Orchestra & Video Games/
KSDU-053 Drums & Effects/
KSDU-054 Ethnic Perc/
KSDU-055 Voices II/
KSDU-056 Performance 1/
KSDU-057 Multiple Inst/
KSDU-058 Industries/
KSDU-059 Synth Bass & Drums/
KSDU-060 Metal-Metalism/
KSDU-061 Sound Tapestry 1/
KSDU-062 Sound Tapestry 2/
KSDU-063 Drums III/
KSDU-064 Drums IV/
KSDU-065 ''D''-Synth Sounds/
KSDU-066 Performance 2/
KSDU-067 Rhythm Section & Guitars/
KSDU-068 Drum Kits/
KSDU-069 Lore, Comb, FX/
KSDU-070 Ambient Drums, Timpani/
Korg DSS-1 Sound Library pic-small.jpg
Korg DSS-1 Sound Library pic-small_small.jpg
Korg DSS-1 Sound Library pic.jpg
Monster Analog/
```